# Can't remove extra white space on my website

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make website using react-bootstrap but I don't know why my website has extra whitespace on the right side, seems like my website default with got expanded. I have 5 component on my website

1. Header
2. About
3. Gallery
4. Destination
5. Footer

the white space won't go even if I delete all the CSS. The white space only gone when I remove all my other components except Header

Any solution?

```
    <div>
      <Header/>

      <Row className="aboutus regular">
        <Col className="aboutusleft" md="12" lg ="6" >
            <h1 className="semibold"> About Us</h1>
            <hr style={{width:'23%', margin:'0', border:'2px solid #10255A'}}></hr>

            <p>Diamond Hotel serves as an urban oasis for both discerning business and leisure travelers. Located in the heart of Samarinda and close to the most prominent culinary tourism object. The hotel itself possess a trendy design with attention to comfort, quality and value based accommodation. It features 75 modern rooms and suites with contemporary design environment to make you feel completely at home.</p>

            <button className="aboutbutton">Learn More</button>
        </Col>

        <Col className="aboutusright text-center" md="12" lg ="6">
          <img src="./img/Group4.png"></img>
        </Col>
      </Row>

      <Row className="gallery">
        <Col className="galleryleft" lg="5">
          <h1>Gallery</h1>
          <hr style={{width:'40%', margin:'0', border:'2px solid #967A50'}}></hr>

          <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur</p>
        </Col>

        <Col className="galleryright" lg="7">
          <Carousel fade>
            <Carousel.Item interval={1000}>
              <img
                className="d-block w-100"
                src="#"
                alt="First slide"
              />
              <Carousel.Caption>
                <h3>First slide label</h3>
              </Carousel.Caption>
            </Carousel.Item>

            <Carousel.Item interval={1000}>
              <img
                className="d-block w-100"
                src="#"
                alt="Second slide"
              />

              <Carousel.Caption>
                <h3>Second slide label</h3>
              </Carousel.Caption>
            </Carousel.Item>

            <Carousel.Item interval={1000}>
              <img
                className="d-block w-100"
                src="#"
                alt="Third slide"
              />

              <Carousel.Caption>
                <h3>Third slide label</h3>
              </Carousel.Caption>
            </Carousel.Item>
          </Carousel>
        </Col>
      </Row>

      <Row className="services">
        <Col className="servicesleft" sm="12" md="12" lg="6">
          <h1>Services During <br/>Your Stay</h1>
          <hr style={{width:'36%', border:'2px solid #967A50'}}></hr>

          <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.</p>
        </Col>

        <Col sm="12" md="12" lg="6">
          <Row className="text-center">
            <Col className="qualityside">
              <img src="./img/bed.png" alt="Bed_logo"></img>
              <h2>High quality bed</h2>

              <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature.</p>
            </Col>

            <Col className="qualityside">
              <img src="./img/concierge.png" alt="Concierge_logo"></img>
              <h2>Concierge Service</h2>

              <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature.</p>
            </Col>
          </Row>

          <Row className="text-center">
            <Col className="qualityside">
              <img src="./img/location.png" alt="Location_logo"></img>
              <h2>Downtown Area</h2>

              <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature.</p>
            </Col>

            <Col className="qualityside">
              <img src="./img/wifi.png" alt="Wifi_logo"></img>
              <h2>24/H Wifi Access</h2>

              <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature.</p>
            </Col>
          </Row>

        </Col>
      </Row>
    
      <Footer />
    </div>
```

My CSS to make the HTML default:

```
html,body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: Montserrat, "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Hi Mate. Kim could you create the codesandbox project for the same and add respective library and share the link, so that we can have a look into this and see where is issue is popping from :)

Comment: Its a default bootstrap behaviour if you didn't wrap everything with `container` or `container-fluid`

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment, do you know any solution to remove the style from container tag ? because when I'm using Container tag it makes my components space narrow (seems like container have some padding).

Answer (score 0):

use something like this:

```
  html,body{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-family: Montserrat, "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    } 

       <Container>
         <Row>
           <Components ... />
         </Row>
       </Container>
```

Answer (score 0):

I often have the problem with bootstrap when a "row" is not wrapped in a "container".
To debug, go to the inspector of your browser and delete section by section to see which one is causing the problem

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I tried using container it did remove the extra white space but Container have some kind of padding and it makes all my components workspace more narrow, any solution to fix this ?